# How to ensure that a cloud function is running every time a new document gets created?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading my questions and answers to my quiz to Firestore. For that I am using following function:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

firestore.settings(settings);
if (data && (typeof data === "object")) {
   Object.keys(data).forEach(docKey => {
      var data_to_push = data[docKey];
      data_to_push['category'] = "Wirtschaft";
      firestore.collection(collectionKey).add(data_to_push).then((res) => {
         console.log("Document " + docKey + " successfully written!");
      }).catch((error) => {
         console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
   });
```

This function works fine, all the documents I need are created but whenever a document get created I have another function that is running:

```
// This function adds the doc ids of newly created questions to an arrayList
exports.AddKeyToArray = functions.region('europe-west1').firestore.document('Questions/{nameId}').onCreate(async (snp, context) => {
    console.log(snp.id);
    console.log(context.params);
    await db.collection("Questions_keys").doc(snp.data().category).update({ "questions": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(snp.id) }).then(() => {
        return console.log("Key  added");
    }).catch(async (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.code === 5) {
            await db.collection("Questions_keys").doc(snp.data().category).set({ "questions": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(snp.id) }).then(() => {
                return console.log("First time key added");
            }).catch(e => {
                return console.log(e);
            })
        }
    })
    return "okay";
})
```

This function basically gets the document id of the previously added question/answer and creates an array with all the document ids of that quiz category (so I then later can get a random question without much reading operations). The problem is that not all document ids are added to the array so I wanted to know if there is a better way to ensure that all the document ids are added into the array.

I upload sometimes 500 documents at once, would be a solution to reduce the documents I upload at once to ensure a better performance of the second function?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why did all documents ids are not added in array, in second function. Is this functions fails?

Comment: Because cloud functions have a trigger limit, of you don:t have a paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that rather than using cloud functions here is to create another collection in your database. This way you can add more questions to that collection easily. This design will increase performance as what you will need is only query the new collection directly and this way you will avoid all the complication needed to manage and work with Cloud Functions.

Comment: What do you mean? I need the first cloud function to upload my questions, there is no other efficient way to do this. And the second function gets the document id of every new document and stores it in an array, there is also no alternative

Comment: what I meant is: using your app - that's uploading the questions - to add also the questions data to a new collection in your database. that will make querying the questions easier and with better performance. If you are uploading the questions from a function here, you can use this function as I described --> add new created documents to a new collection upon a successful add operation.

Answer (score 0):

With help I found a solution: The following function uploads data to firestore and gets the ids of the documents and sets it to an array:

```
...
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

firestore.settings(settings);
if (data && (typeof data === "object")) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(async docKey => {
        var data_to_push = data[docKey];
        data_to_push['category'] = "Deutschland";

        await firestore.collection(collectionKey).add(data_to_push).then(async (res) => {
          var key = (res['_path']['segments'][1]);
            await firestore.collection("Questions_keys").doc(data_to_push['category']).update({ "questions": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(key) }).then(() => {
                 console.log("Key  added: " + key);
            }).catch(async (e) => {
              if (e.code === 5) {
                  await firestore.collection("Questions_keys").doc(data_to_push['category']).set({ "questions": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(key) }).then(() => {
                      return console.log("First time key added");
                  }).catch(e => {
                      return console.log(e);
                  })
              }
                console.log(e);

            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
    });
}
```